# Como fazer um sistema simples de compras?

Tags: php, mysql

Exemplo: tenho um produto com 10 unidades cadastrado em um banco de dados, um cliente compra 1 unidade, essa unidade dá baixa e quantidade do produto vai para 9 unidades.

Como expressar isso em PHP?

Comment: Olá Marcelo Gomes, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Percebi que teve várias perguntas fechadas recentemente. Sugiro que leia o guia [ask] e faça um [tour] para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Qualquer sistema tem como base para gerenciamento de informações diversas base de dados tais como *MySQL, PostgreSQL, MARIADB* ... o CRUD é independente da linguagem de programação que se use.

O CRUD são quatro operações básicas utilizadas em bases de dados relacionais para gerenciar todas as informações a serem estocadas, consultados e eliminadas.

- ***C*** - Create - Criar as informações ...
- ***R*** - Read - Ler as informações ...
- ***U*** - Update - Atualizar as informações ...
- ***D*** - Delete - Excluir as informações ...

A partir do momento que se entende e compreende o processo de CRUD você poderá interagir com o **[SGDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados)** de sua escolha. Um dos mais utilizados do mercado é o MySQL principalmente em se tratando de linguagem de programação PHP.

Uma vez que você estoca todas as suas informações dentro de variáveis e envia e recebe as informações necessárias via comandos `$_GET[]`, `$_POST[]` e `$_REQUEST[]`, você pode enviá-las e recebe-las do seu MySQL. Numa boa parte das vezes, estas informações trafegam via formulários ou comandos acima citados.

> Exemplo de envio e recebimento de informações:

- `$produto = $_POST['nome_produto'];`
- `$preco = $_POST['preco'];`
- `$quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];`

> Exemplo de conexão com o banco de dados

- `mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');`
- `mysql_select_db('db');`

Use MySQLi ou PDO, MySQL está sendo descontinuada.

Uma vez que você está conectado ao banco de dados, use *Xampp* ou *WampServer* para trabalhar em máquina local *(localhost, no seu pc)*, você poderá começar a usar o CRUD ...

> **CRUD**

- **C** - `mysql_query("INSERT INTO (colunas) VALUES (valores) ...);`
- **R** - `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE id_compra = '10');`
- **U** - `mysql_query("UPDATE vendas SET pago = 'pago' WHERE id_compra = '10';`
- **D** - `mysql_query("DELETE FROM vendas WHERE id_compra = '10'");`

Estão aí informações vitais para todas as pessoas que precisam começar a trilhar o caminho das pedras na área de programação.